# Format speed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I want to be able to format and print speed in localised form. I found a few pods that can do that but I'm looking for embedded solution (if possible).

Currently I do next:

```
 let unit = HKUnit.meterUnit(with: .kilo).unitDivided(by: .hour())
 let output = HKQuantity(unit: unit, doubleValue: 12.5).description
```

But in this case I cannot tune anything like use `h` instead of `hr`.

Comment: have you any guidance on how to obtain top speed using HK? Cannot find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said @Allan we have to use `MeasurementFormatter`. Check out the ready to use solution below.

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

let value = NSMeasurement(doubleValue: 12.5, unit: UnitSpeed.milesPerHour)
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.string(from: value as Measurement<Unit>) // prints 12.5 mph
```

Comment: Hey @Arsen, can we change unit of MeasurementFormatter to return km per hour not mile per hour ?

Comment: @KarenKarapetyan hey! Sure, replace UnitSpeed.milesPerHour with UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

The `description` method of `HKQuantity` does not return a localized value and it is meant for debugging, not for display. Convert the `HKQuantity` instance to an `NSMeasurement` and use `NSMeasurementFormatter` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmeasurementformatter)) to localize the value for display.